# Error epoch in VRP

Tags: arcmap, network-analyst, routing, arcgis-rest-api, parameters

I'm currently using VRP for logistical routing needs, but when running it shows the error "Rtg_SaveVrp : 'UtcUtil_ToEpoch' failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null" on the web. I'm having trouble finding those parameters when running VRP on desktop. Did I miss something?